# How to change url without redirection?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am facing rewrite url issue.

Current website url :

```
testwebsite.com/dev/films.php?id=test
```

I want :

```
testwebsite.com/dev/test
```

I tried too many htaccess changes but it is not working.

I think below it must work

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dev/([0-9]+)-([a-z]+)/ http://testwebsite.com/dev/films.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

unfortunately, i got 404 page not found.

When i removed htaccess and tried

```
testwebsite.com/dev/films/test
```

it is working. I dont have c panel access. Is there server side redirection?

I dont know what is the issue? How do i solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go, set this as .htaccess file in your **/dev/** directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  #RewriteBase /dev/

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(css|js|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|bmp)$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,B,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

May require uncomment of **RewriteBase** based on your server setup

Comment: did u understand my question?

Comment: your code is working when i enter anything instead of index. it redirect to  index.php. but i dont want that. when user enter testwebsite.com/dev/test that url rewrite to testwebsite.com/dev/films.php?id=test that

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ films.php?id=$1 [L,B,QSA]` this is work for me

Comment: @DevelopmentTeamSUDO Sorry for long response, so you need that redirect only when it containt **test** or starts with test like **test/films**, am i correct?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that mod_rewrite is working on your Apache server.
You can also redirect using a server-side code by sending header information to the browser before you send any HTML
For example this is how you can do that in PHP.

[PHP redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: did u understand my question? redirection is not my problem. htaccess rule is my problem